# How to determine if point is inside box (three.js)?

Tags: math, three.js, geometry, collision-detection

If we have NON-axis-aligned box, how can we best check if a point lies inside it? (I'm using three.js, so any utility from there can be of help. Three.js contains bounding box concept, but that is axis-aligned bounding box)

Comment: How is your non-axis-aligned box put into non-alignment? Are you using a transformation, or is it geometry which is explicitly positioned in such an orientation?

Comment: There is a lot of approaches. What is the best - depends on how that box is defined.

Comment: @TheJim01 I create the box, translate it and rotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your box is a THREE.BoxGeometry that is rotated, translated and scaled, then you can use its transformation matrix `m` to find if it intersects your point `v`:

- transform `v` and the box by the inverse of `m`
- check if transformed `v` is inside the transformed box (which is now axis aligned)

Here is the code:

```
var box = <Your non-aligned box>
var point = <Your point>

box.geometry.computeBoundingBox(); // This is only necessary if not allready computed
box.updateMatrixWorld(true); // This might be necessary if box is moved

var boxMatrixInverse = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(box.matrixWorld);

var inverseBox = box.clone();
var inversePoint = point.clone();

inverseBox.applyMatrix(boxMatrixInverse);
inversePoint.applyMatrix4(boxMatrixInverse);

var bb = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(inverseBox);

var isInside = bb.containsPoint(inversePoint);
```

And here is a running demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/holgerl/q0z979uy/

Comment: This was my first idea. If this is best approach, they should make a utility method in three.js that does this.

Comment: @croraf I changed my answer to a more general approach and added the code that does this now. Does this work for you?

Comment: @HolgerL You are unnecessarily instantiating 240 objects per second.

Comment: @WestLangley computeBoundingBox is not needed, and if box is not moving: getInverse, box.clone(), inverseBox.applyMatrix, and Box3().setFromObject can be extracted out of the animation loop?

Comment: So what, @WestLangley. The point of my answer is to explain how the problem is solved. Optimized code is usually harder to read and understand. The question was how to solve this problem, not how to write performance optimized code. And the demonstration is to show that it works. I favor readability over memory footprint when I help people.

Comment: If I put these instantiations just before entering the animate loop (end of setup phase) I don't get correct result. Strangely, at that moment box.matrixWorld is identity matrix instead of correct transformation matrix of the box. Any explanations?

Comment: @HolgerL perhaps you could write a more production ready example and highlight the lines that are crucial or even just write the explanation in the comment? This boils down to "transform the point with the inverse".

Comment: @pailhead The answer is fine as it is, as long as I'm concerned. And is also production ready if box is moving. I'm just wondering why is box.matrixWorld identity matrix if I check before animate?

Comment: I solved the issue of box.matrixWorld not being set, with: box.updateMatrixWorld(true); So in the answer I would just change the line box.geometry.computeBoundingBox(); with that line.